# Centos 7 Apache How to allow custom php.ini files

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have a VPS running Apache and CentOS 7. I am trying to use a custom php.ini file in my website directory, /var/www/my-website.com/public_html/php.ini, but my website wont load it. 
If I do a phpinfo() page it says that, Loaded Configuration File = /etc/php.ini. Is there a configuration setting I have to change to allow for custom php.ini files to be loaded?

I guess what my goal is that if there is a php.ini file in a web directory it will override "/etc/php.ini" and use the custom one, in this case, "/var/www/my-website.com/public_html/php.ini"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 100% working solution, but try to go the following steps:

- Copy generic php.ini file to your `/var/www/my-website.com` folder:

  ```
  cp /etc/php.ini /var/www/my-website.com/
  ```
- Edit your custom `php.ini` file as you want and save it
- Locate apache configuration file `httpd.conf` and find `VirtualHost` section that relates to your local domain `my-website.com`
- Add `PHPINIDir` directive to the above section:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/my-website.com/public_html
   ServerName www.my-website.com
   ServerAlias my-website.com
   PHPINIDir /var/www/my-website.com 
   ErrorLog /etc/var/www/my-website.com/error.log
   CustomLog /var/www/my-website.com/requests.log
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Restart Apache web-server and check results:

  ```
  /etc/init.d/httpd restart
  ```

Comment: Works perfectly, the only difference was I had to do, apachectl restart, instead of, /etc/init.d/httpd restart, because that's centos 7 new way to restart Apache web-server. Thank you very much!!!